# Laravel Spatie Activity Log Ip Address Customize

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request, activitylog

I am using Laravel Spatie Activity Log package in my laravel application.
I could customize in each module.

```
 public function tapActivity(Activity $activity, string $eventName)
 {
    $activity->description = "Category is {$eventName}. ";
    $activity->os = getOS();// custom hlper
 }
```

This problem was when I was going to save ip.

```
$activity->ip = $request->ip();
```

I think above field should be added.
But where can we get `$request` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself.

```
$activity->ip = request()->ip();
```

This just worked. :)